# How to open a link in Safari rather than the in app browser

Tags: javascript, browser, instagram

I'm struggling with solution to open instagram stories swipe up links opens into safari browser. I know that is possible because some stories contain links into safari instead of Instagram app Webview.

There is example: https://www.instagram.com/stories/highlights/17893042882461992/
Try to open link with Instagram app.

Solution to open links in browser for Android devices is:
https://medium.com/@sasan.salem/opening-of-your-website-in-the-viewers-external-browser-automatically-instead-of-instagram-s-8aca5ee7e22f